# .NET 6 Windows Service and using the DOTNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

We are converting a number of apps to .NET 6. Most of these are web apps where we can set the environment variable in `web.config.ENV`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Company.services.WebApi.Core.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="CI" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

We are trying to do a similar thing for a Windows Service that is running on .NET 6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Company.ServiceName.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="CI" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Instead of using the `app.config.CI` like we did when the app was .NET 4.72, can we use the `app.config.ENV` to set this environment variable?

We have some machines that host the same service for multiple environments so we need a way to do this and force each service to pull in an environment specific version of `appsettings.ENV.json`

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the information.   I was able to install the service with an environment variable passed in.

windows_service.exe  --environment $env

the --environment is interpreted as DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT in this case allowing the code to take the environment variable and pull in the correct appsettings.env.json

Comment: @mamen: I beg to differ. It's a very good self answer to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a batch file that does

```
@echo off
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=CI
your_process_name.exe
```

2. Using `OpenService()`, `QueryServiceConfig()`, and `ChangeServiceConfig()` functions, change your service executable to be the batch file.

---

If the environment variable affects your code only rather than .NET hosting environment itself; disregard this answer and change your code to read it from `appsettings.json` along with everything else. You can easily get custom config from `appsettings.json`. Most things that affect the asp.net can be done this way with a bit of custom glue code too; but we have encountered things that can't.

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  Are we not able to use the app.config (renamed to the service exe.config) to define that ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable?

Comment: @LanceLyons: I don't know how to do that one; and yeah, almost nothing is in app.config anymore. (It was a bad idea in .NET 4 and it's a bad idea today.)